# Draft JS Modifier.ReplaceText undo/redo error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

## Background:

Using Draft-JS, I've a chunk of code which will replace a word with an Entity on clicking 'Return' so user types in 'i love eggplant' then 'Return' they should see 'i love :eggplant:'

## Problem

After the entity has been added, when I do an undo (`ctrl z`, nothing fancy), it removes all of my sentence rather than just the entity. Based on what I've read about Draft-JS I would have expected it to revert to 'i love eggplant' which is the desired effect.

## Links

- My Example (works as described above) - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMpyPM
- Link Example (works as expected using button click) - https://codepen.io/Kiwka/pen/ZLvPeO

## Code

This code is very stripped down from the full code for readability, yet demos the point correctly

```
const {
  Editor,
  Modifier,
  EditorState,
  RichUtils,
  CompositeDecorator,
  EditorChangeType,
  getDefaultKeyBinding,
} = Draft;

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    const compositeDecorator = new CompositeDecorator([
            { strategy: getEntityStrategy('LINK'), component: LinkComponent },
        ]);

    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(compositeDecorator) };
    this.onChange = (editorState) => { this.setState({editorState}) };
    this.handleReturn = this.handleReturn.bind(this);
  }

  handleReturn(e, editorState) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { start, end, text } = getFullWordWithCoordinates(editorState);
    const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const selectionState = editorState.getSelection();
    const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
      'LINK',
      'MUTABLE',
      { status: 'complete' }
    );
    const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    const newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(contentState,
      selectionState.merge({ anchorOffset: start, focusOffset: end }),
      `:${text}:`,
      null,
      entityKey);
    const newEditorState = EditorState.set(editorState, { currentContent: newContentState });
    this.setState({ editorState: EditorState.moveFocusToEnd(newEditorState) });

    return 'handled';
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div style={{border: '1px solid black', padding: '8px'}}>
        <Editor
          handleReturn={this.handleReturn}
          editorState={this.state.editorState}
          onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function getFullWordWithCoordinates(editorState) {
    const selectionState = editorState.getSelection();
    const anchorKey = selectionState.getAnchorKey();
    const currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const currentContentBlock = currentContent.getBlockForKey(anchorKey);
    const start = selectionState.getStartOffset();
    const end = selectionState.getEndOffset();
    const blockText = currentContentBlock.getText();
    let wholeWordStart = start;
    let wholeWordEnd = end;

    while (blockText.charAt(wholeWordStart - 1) !== ' ' && wholeWordStart > 0) {
        wholeWordStart--;
    }

    while (blockText.charAt(wholeWordEnd) !== ' ' && wholeWordEnd < blockText.length) {
        wholeWordEnd++;
    }
    return {
        text: currentContentBlock.getText().slice(wholeWordStart, wholeWordEnd),
        start: wholeWordStart,
        end: wholeWordEnd,
    };
}

function getEntityStrategy(type) {
    return function(contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
        contentBlock.findEntityRanges(
            (character) => {
                const entityKey = character.getEntity();
                if (entityKey === null) {
                    return false;
                }
                return contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === type;
            },
            callback
        );
    };
}

const LinkComponent = (props) => (<span style={{ background: 'red'}}>{props.children}</span>)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('target')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

the `EditorState.push()` API says `Based on the changeType, this ContentState may be regarded as a boundary state for undo/redo behavior.` I found the user defined `changeType` will make a boundary, so just make a push:

change

```
const newEditorState = EditorState.set(editorState, { currentContent: newContentState });
```

with

```
const newEditorState = EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState ,"addentity");
```